# Express.js storing data from response DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a problem with node/express.js 
I am connected to DB and  I am retriving data from DB and it's saved to 'localhost:3000/interval' as a res.send. I want to storage this to a variable so it is not visiable at ./interval,  parse it, and pass to google Chart API to draw a Chart :) So far i wasn't stuck for so long. Please help :)

Data from DB

```
[{"CZAS":"2017-02-02 21:19:05","PM1":"28","PM25":"40","PM10":"48","ID":"300"},{"CZAS":"2017-02-03 07:17:07","PM1":"45","PM25":"69","PM10":"86","ID":"600"},{"CZAS":"2017-02-03 07:25:58","PM1":"67","PM25":"110","PM10":"139","ID":"900"},{"CZAS":"2017-02-03 07:35:11","PM1":"72","PM25":"121","PM10":"164","ID":"1200"}
```

This is from server.js

```
app.get('/interval', common.listPoints2);
```

Code from common.

```
exports.listPoints2 = function(req, res) {
var data = require('../data.js');
console.log("Getting list points " + req + " res " + res);
data.connect();
console.log("Conecnted ...");
data.fiveMinInterval(1, res);}
```

Here is a function

```
exports.fiveMinInterval = function(req, res) {
var xys = [];
console.log("Get data from DB");
client.query('SELECT time AS CZAS, pm1 AS PM1, pm25 AS PM25, pm10 AS PM10, id AS ID FROM dev_0_data WHERE id%300=0')
.on('result', function(res) {

        res.on('data', function(row) {
    xys.push(row);
        })
    .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log('Result error: ' + inspect(err));
    })
    .on('end', function(info) {
                console.log('Result finished successfully');
    });
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log("Get track points end");

      res.send(xys);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

is "Get track points end" printed?

Note that your on result callback function parameter and your fiveMinInterval parameter "res" has the same variable name.

Comment: 1. Yes it is printed in node console;

Result finished successfully
Get track points end

2. Noticed and changed; 

Well I was thinking that maybe i could store it to file and then read the file with data from DB, but it will not work if i have more sensors.

Comment: What is shown in browser when you call http://localhost:3000/interval ?

Comment: Welp, the "Data from DB"
 [{"CZAS":"2017-02-02 21:19:05","PM1":"28","PM25":"40","PM10":"48","ID":"300"}, etc.

Comment: I'm confuse, when you use app.get() express method is to create a route and show its result on the browser and it seems to be correct what you done.